# How to check if install is from Samsung app store

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I know how to check:

```
 packageManager.getInstallerPackageName(pContext.getPackageName())
```

I know from other StackOverflow answers and my apps in the wild that:

Google Play returns: `com.android.vending`

Amazon returns: `com.amazon.venezia`

If I install with adb I get null value returned from `getInstallerPackageName()`.  Anyone know how to test if install is from Samsung App store?

Comment: I do not have a Samsung device, but I would assume it would be something like com.samsung.* So if you were to search the string the above method returns for the string "samsung" you should be good. I wouldn't imagine there are very many package installers with the string samsung in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Samsung forum thread](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/getinstallerpackagename-return-value-in-samsung-phones/77/177735?boardName=GeneralB) getInstallerPackageName will return null:

> Actually, the value
>   is not being set (the method returns null) when you download an
>   application from SamsungApps. This method is an unreliable source of
>   information in this case.
>
> Regards, Artur 
>   Stepniewski Samsung Developers

This is also what I get using a small test application.